# Array of Array of Array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this class in C#

```
public static class Fases
{
    public static int [,,] fase1 = new int[, , ] { 
        {{1},{1 ,3}}, 
        {{2},{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2 }},
        {{2}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1}} 
    };
}
```

and when I do

```
Fases.fase1[0, 1, 1]
```

it throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you access the arrays like `Fases.fase1[0][1][1]`?

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: This won't compile. See the [Multidimensional Array Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not an Array of Array of Array, it is a 3 dimensional array. Multidimensional arrays must have uniform layout, your code will not compile due to the inner arrays being varying in length.

To get an Array of Array of Array your code would need to be

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = Fases.fase1[0][1][1];
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

public static class Fases
{
    public static int [][][] fase1 = new int[][][] { 
        new int [][] {new int[] {1}, new int[] {1 ,3}}, 
        new int [][] {new int[] {2}, new int[] {2, 2, 2}, new int[] {2, 2, 2 }},
        new int [][] {new int[] {2}, new int[] {3, 1, 1, 1}, new int[]  {3, 1, 1, 1}} 
    };
}
```

[which compiles and runs](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0g7aFn)

Comment: Note that the inner array types can be inferred by the compiler. For instance: `new int [][] { new [] {1}, new [] {1, 3}}}`